# How to load object or module based on variable

Tags: node.js

Being fairly new to NodeJS I wonder what would be the best approach for the following 'problem'.

My main application accepts variables including a `device_type` and a `payload`. The way this `payload` needs to be decrypted depends on the `device_type`.

To avoid using a big case/switch or if-clause and to be able to just drop in a new device when needed; I'm looking for a more object oriented approach.

In PHP I would create a class for each device and 'load' them accordingly from the correct namespace with a decorator. Each class would have a decrypt() method (enforced by using contract)

How would I accomplish a same structure in nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you yourself suggest, you can write those as modules and then include them based on the device type you mention.

*Assuming you have created your modules and put them in the appropriate directory*

```
var decryptors = {
    device_type_1: 'decryptor_module_1',
    device_type_2: 'decryptor_module_2',
};

var decryptor = require(decryptors[input.device_type]);
```

Comment: totally forgot the module required by require() doesn't have a 'class'name. Only reference to the name is the filename.

Comment: Furthermore you can avoid having a mapping by having a `decryptor` (or whatever) property in your device object that will return the name of the decryptor that has to be loaded, or even the object itself.

Comment: But then you should load every possible device at first, and loop through them to find the right 'decryptor' property. Sounds not efficiënt, or do i miss something?

Comment: @stUrb I'm not aware of your workflow, I'm just throwing out ideas in the wild.

Comment: I'm willing to adjust my workflow to a better one :) For now I'll stick to the mapping-table. Is there a non-fatal way to check if the require() exists?